# Find and Replace all data bellow threshold in CSV file python

Tags: python

I have a large CSV file has only an integer numbers like:

```
1121  5552  113  331  5
1121  4     556  333  5
4     5552  8877 4477 15
****  ****  **** **** ****
```

I want data below 50 to be replaced with value 50

```
1121  5552  113  331  50
1121  50    556  333  50
50    5552  8877 4477 50
****  ****  **** **** ****
```

Please; I there any python script to do this job.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
dat = p.read_csv('filename.csv')
dat = dat[dat <50] = 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import csv

data = [map(int, i) for i in csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))]
new_data = [[50 if b < 50 else b for b in i] for i in data]

write = csv.writer(open('filename.csv'))
write.writerow(new_data)
```

Comment: The OP's files aren't actually CSV.  They are tab or whitespace-separated, so they would need to slightly modify this.  I would also use `max(b, 50)` instead of `50 if b < 50 else b`.

Comment: You need to open the file for writing to be able to write to it, and you should always open files with `with`.